# Get enum size from parent interface in java

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have an interface `ParentInterface` and have multiple enums that implement it: `ChildEnum1` and `ChildEnum2`. I have a method to which I pass the `ParentInterface` as a parameter.

Based on what `ChildEnum` is passed to this method, I want to get the size of the enum. How can I do this? The `values.length()` method works only on `enums`, but we are only passing in the `ParentInterface` to the caller.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: What about definining a `size()` method in `ParentInterface`?

Comment: @fge: My enums have static methods, but interface cannot have a static `size()` method.

Comment: But you are not invoking method on class, but on instance you pass to your method. You don't need to make `size()` method static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reflection, using [`Class#getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) (quick and dirty demo):

```
package com.stackoverflow.so21821751;

public class Test {
    interface ParentInterface {
        void someMethod();
    }

    static enum ChildEnum1 implements ParentInterface {
        FOO, BAR, LOL;

        @Override
        public void someMethod() {
            // something
        }
    }

    static enum ChildEnum2 implements ParentInterface {
        FOO, BAR;

        @Override
        public void someMethod() {
            // something
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        foo(ChildEnum1.BAR); // 3
        foo(ChildEnum2.FOO); // 2
    }

    private static void foo(final ParentInterface i) {
        System.out.println(i.getClass().getEnumConstants().length);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is super helpful! On a different note, on an architectural side, is using Reflection a good design choice? I have heard people having never-use-reflection philosophy and so I refrain from using it for any core business logic. What's your thought?

Comment: Matter of taste IMHO, this is more "introspection" than "reflection". I see a problem with reflection when you use it to do stuff you are not supposed to do directly (like access a private field, ...)